# Eclipse not launching after deletion of $HOME/.metadata folder

Tags: java, eclipse

I made a mistake and deleted the `.metadata` folder in my home directory (I'm using Linux redhat.) Now, Eclipse doesn't launch at all. The window with the eclipse icon shows up and nothing happens after that.

Any solution to this? Did it actually even depend on that .metadata directory?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe restore the .metadata file?

Comment: I did rm -rf it. I copied the .metadata (after deleting the .log and .lock files there) to $HOME. Testing it.

Answer (score 1):

First thing I would try is opening Eclipse in a new workspace.  The other thing you can also try is starting Eclipse in clean mode, just add -clean.